# how to give navigation time to geckowebbrowser before navigate anoter time

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, gecko, geckofx

i am creating simple webpage reloader program. i want to reload a web page few times. In my program i am using gecko webbrowser control, and i am using a progressBar as pege reload progress.

what i am trying to do is when gecko loads web page the progressBar value will incresse 1 time, and i am increasing it 5 times doing 5 time navigation. when navigation completes progressBar will increase 1 time.

Below is my code that i used in my program but it's not working well. when i navigate,  the progressbar increases full in fist time, it's not increasing one by one, it get's full in one time.

please tell me what i need to do to give navigation time to gecko webbrowser control so that it can load web page succefully and then go for next time navigation.

```
while(progressbar1.Value != 5)

{

    GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);

    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1;

}
```

Comment: Does it support a navigation complete/document loaded event?

Comment: yes it support's DocumentCompleted event but i don't know how to use it